# Stop component from executing code in IDE (BCB)

Tags: c++, c++builder-2009

I made a new component which executes the code in my constructor whilst being on the IDE. I need to stop it from doing that and only execute the code while it's actually executing the program. I'm using C++ Builder 2009.

Comment: You mean that the compiler computes the result at compile-time, to make the program run faster? That's usually not a problem.  :-)

Comment: No, when I open my Form it already executes the code to populate a dropdown, which is something it isn't supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if (ComponentState.Contains(csDesigning))
    ShowMessage("Design-time");
  else
    ShowMessage("Runtime");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I couldn't find that anywhere.

Comment: Oh, I had to look it up for BCB, but I remembered that I could do it in Delphi, so ..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the new component you've made that makes the IDE do that.